# Installing process of DotNetNuke (Dnn.Platform-8.0.2)

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke

Downloaded source package of DotnetNuke and I am new in dotnetNuke. Can anyone help me to clarify the process of installing DotnetNuke.

I am following this [Install DNN](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2009/11/16/DotnetNuke-Module-Development-Setup-Development-Environment.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a tutorial on installing DNN8 [found here](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/DNN8-Tutorials).

[You can also follow this text tutorial](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1)

> Setting up your development environment can vary based on what your
>   end goal is. If you are doing module development for your own use, and
>   within your own DNN environments, you can ignore a few of the settings
>   below. If you are doing module development with the idea that you
>   might turn around and give the modules away, or sell them, then you
>   will likely want to follow the guidelines set forth below to support
>   the widest array of DNN installation environments.
>
> I recommend that each developer have their own local development
>   environment, with a local IIS website running DotNetNuke, and a SQL
>   Server 2008/2012 (not express, though you can use it) database for the
>   website. Having an individual development environment makes group
>   module development far easier than if you share
>   environments/databases.
>
> Choosing a DotNetNuke Version Choosing a version of DotNetNuke is
>   important when you start your development for couple of reasons. For
>   modules that you are developing for yourself, you need to ask, what is
>   the minimum version of DotNetNuke that you have in production. Are you
>   running DNN 5.6.1? Are you running 6.2.6, 7.0.0, 7.0.6? Based on the
>   answer you can determine what version of DNN you should setup as your
>   development environment. You shouldn't be developing on a newer
>   version of DNN than what you have running in production. As with
>   everything there are ways around this, but I am not going to go into
>   the details on that in this tutorial.
>
> As a developer working to create modules and release those, you might
>   have production sites that are running on the latest and greatest
>   version of DNN, but what about your customers? Or your potential
>   customers? You have to ask yourself, do you want to provide support
>   for really old versions of DotNetNuke? From a development perspective
>   you will probably say no, but from a business perspective, you might
>   say yes, and here’s why. Not everyone upgrades DotNetNuke websites as
>   they should, and often times you will find that some people never
>   upgrade. While I don’t advise taking that approach to managing a
>   DotNetNuke website, it is a fact of life that people don’t always
>   upgrade and there are thousands of people, if not tens of thousands,
>   that have sites that aren’t running on the latest version of DNN. You
>   should take that into account when you are doing your module
>   development, if you compile your module against an older version of
>   DNN then your module should run on newer versions of as well, for
>   example. If you compile your module against DotNetNuke 6.2.6 it will
>   likely run on every version of DNN released since then. Though there
>   are extended cases where this won’t always work, DNN strives to
>   maintain backwards compatibility, this isn't always possible.
>
> You might also want to use features that are only available starting
>   with a specific version of DotNetNuke, such as the workflow
>   functionality found starting in DNN 5.1, in that case you may choose
>   not to support older versions of the platform out of necessity. This
>   will minimize the market in which you can sell your modules, but also
>   can make for less support and an easier development cycle due to the
>   features that DNN provides.
>
> Choosing a Package Now here’s one that may baffle you a bit. I’m going
>   to recommend that you use the INSTALL package for whatever version of
>   DotNetNuke that you download. What? The INSTALL package? What about
>   the SOURCE package? Well you can use the source, but you don’t need
>   it. The module development that I’m setting you up for doesn't require
>   the DNN source, and using the INSTALL package makes your development
>   environment cleaner. We aren't going to be opening the DotNetNuke
>   project when we do our module development, so why have the files
>   sitting around for nothing? Also, if you've ever tried to use the
>   SOURCE package for anything, you'll know it isn't easy.
>
> The steps for setting up your development environment will apply to
>   both the Community and Professional editions of DotNetNuke.
>
> Installation Configuration Once you have the version selection out of
>   the way you can go through the installation process. While I’m not
>   going to walk you through the minutest of details of each step of
>   installing DotNetNuke in this post, I will at least try to point you
>   in the right direction for each step.
>
> Download the INSTALL package of the version of DotNetNuke you want to
>   use in your development environment.
>
> Extract the files in the INSTALL package to a location of your
>   choosing, this location is where you will point IIS (the web server)
>   when we can configure the website. In my environment I typically use
>   c:\websites\dnndev.me\ (One item of note: you may need to right click
>   on the ZIP file and choose Properties before extracting, on the
>   properties window if you have an UNBLOCK option, click that. Some
>   versions of Windows have started blocking files within the DotNetNuke
>   ZIP files, which will cause you problems later during the actual
>   install.)
>
> Setup IIS IIS is the web server that comes with Windows computers. DNN
>   7 requires IIS 7 or later (7,7.5,8.0), so you will need at least
>   Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows Server 2008 R2,
>   Windows Server 2012.
>
> In IIS you should create a new website (Note: If you use an existing
>   website in IIS be sure to add the HOST binding for DNNDEV.ME), and
>   point to the folder where you extracted the INSTALL package.
>
> Note: With DotNetNuke 7.0+, .NET Framework 4.0 is required, so be sure
>   that your application pool is configured to run under 4.0, and not
>   2.0.
>
> Set File Permissions Setting up the file permissions for your DNN
>   install is often the step that causes the most trouble. You should
>   right click on the FOLDER in which you extracted DNN
>   (c:\websites\dnndev.me) and choose properties. Choose the Security
>   tab. You need to add permissions for the account in which your
>   website's application pool is running under. You will want to setup
>   the permissions to give the account Full or Modify permissions for the
>   DNNDEV.ME folder. Which account you will use will vary based on your
>   version of IIS, here’s a simple list of some of the default accounts
>   based on the version of IIS.
>
> IIS Version Operating System Account IIS 7 Windows Vista, Windows
>   Server 2008 localmachine\Network Service IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 R2,
>   Windows 7 IIS AppPool\APPPOOLNAME IIS 8 Windows 2012, Windows 8 IIS
>   AppPool\APPPOOLNAME
>
> Note: If you are using IIS7.5/8.0 you’ll notice in the above table
>   that we have APPPOOLNAME in the identity, this is because when you
>   setup a new website in IIS a new application pool is created. In place
>   of you should type in the name of the application pool that was
>   created. You can also bypass this and configure your application pool
>   to use the Network Service account instead of a dynamic account if you
>   would like.
>
> Database Configuration In SQL Server you should go through and create
>   a new database. I always create a database with the same name as the
>   website, so in this case DNNDEV.ME. Once you have created the
>   database, create a user that can access that database. I always use
>   SQL authentication, turn off the enforce password requirements, and
>   give the user DB Owner and Public access to the DNNDEV.ME database.
>   Remember the username and password you create here as you will need
>   them when you walk through the Installation screen for DotNetNuke.
>
> DotNetNuke Installation Screen Populate the installation screen with
>   the standard DNN information, Host username, password, etc. For the
>   Database option, choose Custom and configure your database connection,
>   providing the Server IP/Name, the Database name (dnndev.me). For the
>   database authentication you'll want to choose the option that allows
>   you to enter the username/password for the database user that you
>   created previously.
>
> Now there are two additional options you can configure, normally I
>   would tell you not to modify these, but from a development environment
>   perspective I do recommend that you change the objectQualifier
>   setting. It should be blank by default, you should type in “dnn”
>   (without quotes), this will prepend “dnn_” to all of the objects that
>   get created by DNN such as Tables and Stored Procedures. This is not
>   something I recommend from a production stand point, but if you are
>   developing modules for sale, then supporting objectQualifier in your
>   development is recommended. It will save you time down the road if you
>   have a customer who has an objectQualifier defined on their production
>   databases.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable concern sir

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following video and it has total two parts one and two part links are givenbelow

[Part one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLGCn7KZbCQ)

[Part two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Cw1G5Z7nZI&t=49s)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes